# get_term_children even term have no post

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an custom taxonomy with name "Products",now what i want to get a specific term number of children,even term child have no post.

Right now my code is :

```
$taxonomy_name = 'products';
$term_id = "";
$term_data = get_term_by( "name", $atts['name'], $taxonomy_name);
$termchildren = get_term_children($term_data->term_id, $taxonomy_name );
return count($termchildren);
```

Its works perfectly - but it counts if term have post.but i want,if term have no post,still it counts.

Answer (score 1):

Use this way.

```
<?php

$parent_cat_arg = array('hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 );
$parent_cat = get_terms('category',$parent_cat_arg);//category name

foreach ($parent_cat as $catVal) {

    echo '<h2>'.$catVal->name.'</h2>'; //Parent Category

    $child_arg = array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => $catVal->term_id );
    $child_cat = get_terms( 'category', $child_arg );

        $count_child =count($child_cat);

        echo $count_child;    

}
?>
```

Output

[image]